# ポート番号 80 を使用しているプロセスはどれをkillすればいいか知りたい

Tags: linux, macos, docker, bash

現在Dockerを勉強しており、[はじめてのDocker for Mac](https://qiita.com/kobori_akira/items/0cc993caeb20d77cd367) を参考にしています。

結論から言うと、**どのプロセスIDをkillすればいいのか？またなぜ複数あるうちのそのプロセスIDをkillするのか**教えていただければと思います。

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx
```

を実行したところ、「すでに80は使用している」という内容のエラーがでました。
そこで80のプロセスをkillしようと思ったのですが、以下のように表示され、どれをkillすればいいかわかりません。

```
sudo lsof -P -i:80

COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd      97 root    4u  IPv6        0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd     409 _www    4u  IPv6        0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd   55456 _www    4u  IPv6        0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd   55457 _www    4u  IPv6        0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
httpd   55458 _www    4u  IPv6        0t0  TCP *:80 (LISTEN)
```

複数出ているためどれをkillしていいかわからず、また、80ポートのものをkillして問題が起こらないのか、影響範囲はどうか、といったことがわからないため安易にkillできません。

ネットで調べたのですが、明確な回答にはたどり着けなかったため質問させていただきました。

**どのプロセスIDをkillすればいいのか？またなぜ複数あるうちのそのプロセスIDをkillするのか**教えていただければと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` コマンドの実行結果一覧に `httpd` と出ているので、恐らく Apache のプロセスが既に起動しており `:80` のポートを使用している状態なのだと思います。

以下のコマンドを実行して Apache を停止してみてください。

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
```

Comment: `80` ポートを使用している複数のプロセスはすべて `Apache httpd` の親プロセスが管理している子プロセスなので、その親プロセスに `apachectl` で停止指示を送ると全部停止する（からこれだけでよい）って書くとより分かりやすくなる気のせいがします。